# Detecting if Android/iOS device is already playing music through Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am developing a game on unity and I want to stop the in-game music if the user is already playing some music when the game is launched. Is there a way to detect if music is being played already on the deivce?

Thanks!

EDIT---
I wrote a native plugin to test if device is playing. But what unity does is I think it takes the speaker under it control. So the native code will always return true even though any sort of music is not playing.

I made a unity project with an empty scene and nothing related to audio. I tested out the plugin and it still returned true. I just made a simple native android application and tested out the code and I got a correct true and false. So Unity basically uses the speakers even when nothing is playing.

Is there a solution for this ?

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If Unity itself won't tell you, it's at least possible to write a native plugin that you could call to find out. Or maybe you could get a plugin someone else already wrote.

Comment: It would definitely be possible through a native plugin. Just wanted to know if there is a Unity API for it.

Comment: Which is why I made it just a comment, and not an answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your comment:

> It would definitely be possible through a native plugin. Just wanted to know if there is a Unity API for it.

Unity does not have any built-in way to check this.

Comment: I wrote a native plugin to test if device is playing. But what unity does is I think it takes the speaker under it control. So the native code will always return true even though any sort of music is not playing.

I made a unity project with an empty scene and nothing related to audio. I tested out the plugin and it still returned true. I just made a simple native android application and tested out the code and I got a correct true and false. So Unity basically uses the speakers even when nothing is playing.

Is there a solution for this ?